# How to set repository as the root when using /docs as the source for Github pages?

Tags: github-pages

If I set my githubpages repo to `<username>.github.io`, anything in the root gets displayed on `<username>.github.io`

But I want to use the `/docs` feature so I can have a static site generator in the root of the project that outputs to the `/docs` folder

so the [docs](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/) say

```
- have a /docs folder in the root of the repository
- not follow the repository naming scheme <username>.github.io or <orgname>.github.io
```

so, I rename my repo,  "blah"

but now nothing shows up at `<username>.github.io`   and the page is at `<username>.github.io/blah`

so when using `/docs`  how do you set the repo as the root of the site `<username>.github.io`?

Answer (score 0):

After contacting github support, it turns out you can't ( currently ) you need to use one of their other methods that use `<username>.github.io`

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem with this.
After hours of try I figured out that:

1. If you use a repository named '.github.io' or '.github.com', you could only use their pre-provided file structure, which means you can't select the source for the github-pages service.
2. If you rename the repo to other name which not match the auto-serve pattern(.github.io| ...com), you will be able to choose the source.
3. If case [2], you need to add an empty file named '.nojekyll' under /docs folder, and put all files including CNAME and index.html and asset files(images, css,etc.,) here.

ref: https://www.docslikecode.com/articles/github-pages-python-sphinx/